# Remove additional comma in Magento-2 price

Tags: magento2, price, localisation

There is an additional comma in the product price .. you can see live :
https://clothat.com/elnaksha-1.html

I want to remove it .. and is this problem related with the Arabic Language ?

[image: additional comma]